# Numpy sum of values between arrays of indices with a wraparound condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a large numpy array of floats and 2 arrays of indices I'm looking for an elegant way to sum all the values contained between the given indices by following the following rules:

- when index1 > index0, summation happens in a straight forward fashion
- when index1 < index0, summation "wraparounds" the values.

so for example:

```
import numpy as np

# Straight forward summation when index1 > index0
values = np.array([0.,10.,20.,30.,40.,50.,60.,70.])
index0 = np.array([0,3])
index1 = np.array([2,6])
# Desired Result: np.array([30,180]) # (0+10+20),(30+40+50+60)

# Wrap around condition when index1 < index0
index0 = np.array([5])
index1 = np.array([1])
# Result: np.array([190]) # (50+60+70+0+10)
```

Because i'm dealing with rather large arrays, i'm looking for an elegant numpy-centric solution if possible.

Comment: Can you double check your example, the boundaries and expected results seem off...

Comment: Could there be overlaps of those ranges, something like `index0 = np.array([0,3]) and index1 = np.array([4,6])`?

Comment: @Divakar yes. `index0` and `index1` could also be represented as a single list of pairs, ex: `index = np.array([[0,4],[3,6],...])`... if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
# store all cumulative sums (adding 0 at the start for the empty sum)
cs = np.insert(np.cumsum(values), 0, 0) 

# then for each indexing get the result in constant time (linear in index0/1 size):
result = np.where(index0 < index1, 0, cs[-1]) + cs[index1+1]-cs[index0]
```